# How can I configure Polymer's platinum-sw-* to NOT cache one URL path?

Tags: polymer, service-worker, hoodie

How can I configure Polymer's platinum-sw-cache or platinum-sw-fetch to cache all URL paths except for /_api, which is the URL for Hoodie's API?  I've configured a platinum-sw-fetch element to handle the /_api path, then platinum-sw-cache to handle the rest of the paths, as follows:

```
<platinum-sw-register auto-register
                      clients-claim
                      skip-waiting
                      on-service-worker-installed="displayInstalledToast">
  <platinum-sw-import-script href="custom-fetch-handler.js"></platinum-sw-import-script>
  <platinum-sw-fetch handler="HoodieAPIFetchHandler"
                 path="/_api(.*)"></platinum-sw-fetch>
  <platinum-sw-cache default-cache-strategy="networkFirst"
                     precache-file="precache.json"/>
  </platinum-sw-cache>
</platinum-sw-register>
```

custom-fetch-handler.js contains the following.  Its intent is simply to return the results of the request the way the browser would if the service worker was not handling the request.

```
var HoodieAPIFetchHandler = function(request, values, options){
  return fetch(request);
}
```

What doesn't seem to be working correctly is that after user 1 has signed in, then signed out, then user 2 signs in, then in Chrome Dev Tools' Network tab I can see that Hoodie regularly continues to make requests to BOTH users' API endpoints like the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/_api/?hoodieId=uw9rl3p
http://localhost:3000/_api/?hoodieId=noaothq
```

Instead, it should be making requests to only ONE of these API endpoints.  In the Network tab, each of these URLs appears twice in a row, and in the "Size" column the first request says "(from ServiceWorker)," and the second request states the response size in bytes, in case that's relevant.

The other problem which seems related is that when I sign in as user 2 and submit a form, the app writes to user 1's database on the server side.  This makes me think the problem is due to the app not being able to bypass the cache for the /_api route.

Should I not have used both platinum-sw-cache and platinum-sw-fetch within one platinum-sw-register element, since the docs state they are alternatives to each  other?

Comment: Just got something similar working. This helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, what you're doing should work, and it's a legitimate approach to take.

If there's an HTTP request made that matches a path defined in `<platinum-sw-fetch>`, then that custom handler will be used, and the default handler (in this case, the `networkFirst` implementation) won't run. The HTTP request can only be responded to once, so there's no chance of multiple handlers taking effect.

I ran some local samples and confirmed that my `<platinum-sw-fetch>` handler was properly intercepting requests. When debugging this locally, it's useful to either add in a `console.log()` within your custom handler and check for those logs via the `chrome://serviceworker-internals` Inspect interface, or to use the same interface to set some breakpoints within your handler.

What you're seeing in the Network tab of the controlled page is expected—the service worker's network interactions are logged there, whether they come from your custom `HoodieAPIFetchHandler` or the default `networkFirst` handler. The network interactions from the perspective of the controlled page are also logged—they don't always correspond one-to-one with the service worker's activity, so logging both does come in handy at times.

So I would recommend looking deeper into the reason why your application is making multiple requests. It's always tricky thinking about caching personalized resources, and there are several ways that you can get into trouble if you end up caching resources that are personalized for a different user. Take a look at the line of code that's firing off the second `/_api/` request and see if it's coming from an cached resource that needs to be cleared when your users log out. `<platinum-sw>` uses the [`sw-toolbox` library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox) under the hood, and you can make use of its [`uncache()` method](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox#toolboxuncacheurl-options) directly within your custom handler scripts to perform cache maintenance.

Comment: I put console.log() and debugger statements inside and outside my custom handler function, unregistered the service worker instance, closed and reopened the tab, and don't see those log messages in the chrome://serviceworker-internals log, nor does the debugger pause execution at my debugger statements.  How can I verify whether my custom handler is running?

Comment: My problem was that I created two instances of Hoodie.  I'm marking your answer as the correct one because you gave such a good and helpful answer and you recommended I carefully study the code which made the second request, which led to the solution.  Thank you!